# Is there a way to avoid BadImageFormatException on Assembly.Load by pre-analyzing

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, badimageformatexception

I have an application, that loads all the .dlls the user puts into a special directory.
If they are created wrong (x86,x64) or something else, an BadImageFormatException is thrown. Thats ok, but I don't like avoid exceptions. So the question is:

Is there a way to analyse the file in advance to NOT get an exception?

- Check if it's the right platform target
- Check if it's unmanaged..
- - other possible issues.

Main goal is to avoid the exception. It would also be OK to get a bool that tells, if it will work.

Current Code:

```
    private Assembly TryLoadAssmbly(string file)
    {
        Assembly result;

        try
        {
            result = Assembly.LoadFile(file);
        }
        catch (BadImageFormatException exc)
        {
            Log.Error($"File \"{file}\" could not be loaded");
            result = null;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: whatever check you do, you still need to handle exceptions, since things might change between the check and method call. So I would just accept that some methods require exception handling and focus on providing as good error information as possible to help the user correct the problem.

Comment: That is a good point it should mention. I don't think, I could to get arround all types of exception, if there are custom checks. I'll leave the try-catch anyway.

Comment: There is a [CLI header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/file-format) you could read, so many checks should be possible. I would expect there to be some libraries for this, but It is not something I have experience with. You might want to ask at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it's worthy of the effort BUT you could use `PEReader`:

```
static bool IsLoadableManagedAssembly(string assemblyPath) {
   using var reader = new PEReader(new StreamReader(assemblyPath));
   ...
}
```

First of all exclude files without metadata, they're not assemblies for sure:

```
if (!reader.HasMetadata)
   return false;
```

Now you can check if it's 32 or 64 bit...and things get a bit more complicate. There is a nice `reader.PEHeaders.PEHeader.Magic` you can use to check if the file is 64 bit only: `PEMagic.PE32Plus` (and you can stop here if your application is 32 bit only.

Still reading? Then you're targeting *Any CPU* or X64. You have this in the COFF object:

```
bool mightBe64 = reader.PEHeaders.CoffHeader.Machine == Machine.IA64
   || reader.PEHeaders.CoffHeader.Machine == Machine.Unknown;

if (Environment.Is64BitProcess != mightBe64)
   return false;
```

Now we can handle *Any CPU* with "required 32 bit":

```
bool requires32 = reader.PEHeaders.CorHeader.Flags.HasFlag(CorFlags.Requires32Bit);
if (Environment.Is64BitProcess && requires32)
   return false;
```

Note that you could (should?) use `CorFlags.ILOnly` also for *Any CPU*.

There is also a `Characteristics.Bit32Machine` in `CoffHeader.Characteristics` but I am not sure if could be anything not already covered.

---

In the top of everything...you will still need to handle `BadImageFormatException` because the file could be invalid or we missed something else here.

---

Did you consider caching the result of your search so you won't need to "try" to load them after the first time?

---

References:

- https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/anatomy-of-a-net-assembly-pe-headers/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.portableexecutable.pereader?view=net-6.0

Comment: Very nice, thanks a lot. As a small addition from me, the machine to use was Amd64, which I believe is the common type for x64.